# Smallest counterexample: For any positive integer n, prove $\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1) = n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1) = n^2$$

I am trying to prove the equation above by smallest counterexample. The following is what I have so far.

Proof.
Assume for the sake of contradiction that the statement is false for some positive integer. Let $C$ be the set of counterexamples. That is, $$C = \{x \in Z^+ : \sum_{k=1}^x (2k-1) \neq x^2 \}$$

By assumption, $C$ is not empty. By the Well-Ordering Principle, $C$ has a smallest element, which we will call $x$. Note that $x \neq 1$, since $\sum_{k=1}^1 (2k-1) = 1$ and $(1)^2 = 1$, so they are equal.

So $x-1$ is a positive integer that is $\notin C$. Therefore, the claim holds for $x-1$, that is, $$\sum_{k=1}^{(x-1)} (2k-1) = (x-1)^2$$.

This is where I'm stuck. I've tried expanding out the right-hand side into polynomial form as well as the lefthand side to be out of sigma notation. However, I must be missing an idea while I do this. Tips?

Comment: It's basically a *really* convoluted induction proof. Now see what happens when you add $2x - 1$ to $\sum_{k=1}^{(x-1)} (2k-1) = (x-1)^2$, that is, consider $\sum_{k=1}^{x} (2k-1)$. You know that's just $(x - 1)^2 + 2x - 1$, which gives a contradiction because...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{(x-1)} (2k-1) &= (x-1)^2 \\
(-2x+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{x} (2k-1) &= x^2-2x+1 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{x} (2k-1) &= x^2
\end{align}$$

If it is false for $x-1$, the above shows that it is also false for $x$, which is your contradiction.

Comment: Wow, that's much more simple than I thought. I think I overthink these smallest counterexample proofs way too much and that's why I keep running into trouble. Thank you and those above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can prove it simply bu Mathmatical induction .
Note that it's true when $n=1$& $n=2$
So assume it's true for $n=t$ $\implies$ $\sum_{k=1}^t (2k-1) = t^2$

Now for $n=t+1$ $\implies $
$\sum_{k=1}^{t+1} (2k-1) = \sum_{k=1}^t (2k-1) +(2(t+1)-1)=t^2+2t+1=(t+1)^2$

Thus it's true for $n=t+1$, then by mathematical induction it's true for any $n \in$ $\mathbb{N}$